# Ordinary differential equations-method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the method of undetermined coefficients to solve the IVP
$y′′ + 4y′ + 4y = (3 + x)e^{−2x},\; y(0) = 2,\; y′(0) = 5$ .

My answer (partial)

$r^2 + 4r +4 = 0$

$ (r+ 2)^2 = 0$

$r = -2$

$y_h = (c_1 +xc_2) e^{-2x}$

$y_p =(xc_1 + x^2c_2)e^{-2x} $

Unable to reach final answer. Need help!

Comment: Try another way.

Comment: Consider $y_p = c_1+c_2 x+c_3 x^2+c_3 x^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your homogeneous solution is correct, but your particular solution should at least use different constants.   Because $(c_1+c_2 x) e^{-2 x}$ returns zero upon substitution into the differential equation (because it is the homogeneous solution), the particular solution should contain the next two higher powers, i.e.

$$y_p(x) = (a x^2+b x^3) e^{-2 x}$$

Substituting this into the equation returns

$$y_p''+4 y_p'+4 y_p = 2 (a + 3 b x) e^{-2 x} = (3+x) e^{-2 x}$$

Equate coefficients of $x$, i.e., $2 a=3$, $6 b = 1$.  The solution is then

$$y(x) = \left (c_1+c_2 x +\frac{3}{2} x^2 + \frac16 x^3\right )e^{-2 x}$$

Find $c_1$ and $c_2$ from the initial conditions.

$$y(0)=2 \implies c_1=2$$
$$y'(0)=5 \implies -2 c_1+c_2 = 5 \implies c_2=9$$

Comment: Thanks for the clear and precise working. Very well explained, i have understood where i made mistakes. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just noting additional point, following @Ron's answer. If you have: $$a_ny^{(n)}+\cdots+a_1y'+a_0y=Q(x)$$ and  two following conditions are fulfilled:

1. The characteristics equation of the associated homogenous OE has an $r$ multiple roots.
2. $Q(x)$ contains a term such that, ignoring constants, is $x^t$ times a term a(x) in $y_c$.

Then in this case the $y_p$ will be a linear combination of $$x^{k+r}a(x)$$  and all its linearly independent derivatives.

I think you can find out @Ron's answer better after this points. (-:

Comment: $+1 \ddot\smile$